# rendering db columns in cfsearch results

Tags: coldfusion

Below is the code that does the index, and the cfsearch code that reads

The index:

```
<cfquery name="Qryname" datasource="dsnnane">
SELECT id, eid, title
FROM tbl1
</cfquery>

<cfindex  
    query="Qryname" 
    collection="events" 
    action="Update" 
    type="Custom" 
    title="title" 
    key="id" 
    body="eid,title">
```

Search Results

```
    <cfsearch   
    collection="events" 
    name="Qryname" 
    criteria="#Form.Criteria#"> 

    <!--- Output the record set. ---> 
    <cfoutput> 
    Your search returned #Qryname.RecordCount# result(s). 
    </cfoutput> 

    <cfoutput query="Qryname"> 
    <a href="page.cfm?eid=#eid#">#title#</a>

    </cfoutput>
```

The problem is that I can only output the column which I specified as the title in cfindex. If I try to output any other column other than that which I specified as the title, the system says that the var is undefined.

In this case it says that eid is undefined.

I see in the documentation that the column values can be output

Please see part 3 in "Search and display the query results", which is under "Indexing data returned by a query"

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7b35.html

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the custom fields in cfindex. If you read the ref for cfindex, you'll see that it supports up to 4 custom fields, ranging from custom1 to custom4.

Simply assign a db table column to one of the custom fields, re-index, then access that custom field in cfsearch

```
<cfindex  
    query="Qryname" 
    collection="events" 
    action="Update" 
    type="Custom" 
    title="title" 
    key="id" 
    body="eid,title"
    custom1="eid">
```

cfsearch:

```
<cfoutput query="Qryname"> 
<a href="page.cfm?eid=#custom1#">#title#</a>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by doing:

```
<cfdump var="#Qryname#" />
```

To see what is returned from the cfsearch.

Comment: Thank you. Have done a cfdump on my code as well as the code from the documentation, and they are the same. It looks like I assumed that the data in the link that I provided came from the tables in the db, (title, score, key, summary, custom1, columnlist) but it is not so, these data come from cfsearch. Question, how do you link search results from cfsearch? (The url var is in the same record as the search result)

Comment: also, the only data from the db that is in cfsearch is that which was defined in the title field in cfindex